# Lost phone number and PayPal need verify by phone number

Tags: account-recovery, paypal

My account was locked I can't log on my account and my recovery option was my email only but I made my account when I still had my old number, and have no way of accessing that number, and can't send to a different phone number.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

> [image]
>
> **https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/contact-us**
>
> ### ____________________________________________________________
>
> [image]

Comment: can somebody transcribe this answer into text in case images are lost? or just copy over the text since it should be available at the link